# How to compare database tables and display to the user

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm developing a surfing site. In it, there is a section called My Ideal Surfboard.

Where the user will enter their data ( `Name`,`email`, `weight and height` and `experience` (beginner, intermediate or advanced)).

I will save this data in the database and based on user characteristics (height, weight and experience) I will display the ideal type of surfboard.

The section is already done and is now also recording the user data in the database. I got a table/reference list of all surfboard measures according to the height and weight of the user.

[image: Table with surfboard sizes according to the user profile]

To return the ideal surfboard, I need to get user data and compare it with this table/reference list.

I thought about doing it this way,

Divided into three tables/sections: `Experience`,`Height and Weight` and `surfboard model`.

Each table I'll assign an ID:

User Experience -> ID a, b, c 
Weight and Height -> ID a, b, c, d .... 
Surfboard Model -> ID a, b, c, d ....

[image: User Experience]

Table with the user experience, an ID for each.

[image: Height and Weight]

Table with the ratio of weight and height of the user, an ID for each.

[image: Surfboard model]

Final Table with surfboard models, an ID for each.

For the result I will, somehow, compare the `Exp` with the `Height + Weight` table, generating an ID number or X is compared with the third table ID (surfboard model) and thus obtaining the result. I don't know if it was very clear explanation, anything can ask me.

My doubt is:
Is correct that my logic?
This is the best way to do?
In code, how can I do this?

Any kind of help is welcome!

So far I only have the code to register the data in the database:

--I think the HTML form don't is useful. If someone request, I post here or on Pastebin.

```
function cadastrar($nome,$email,$estilo,$experiencia,$altura,$peso){          //INSERE OS DADOS NO BANCO
     global $wpdb;
     // the name of our table
    $table = 'aa_minhaprancha';

    // data is an array with the format column_name => data
    $data = array(
      'nome' => $nome,
      'email' => $email,
      'estilo' => $estilo,
      'experiencia' => $experiencia,
      'altura' => $altura,
      'peso' => $peso,
    );

    // run the insert
    $updated = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data );

    // if it didn't update get the error
    if ( ! $updated ) {
      $wpbb->print_error();
    }

}
```

The database is in Wordpress. However, there is no problem if there is any help in MySql. I will convert.

To recapitulate:

**Want I want to do?** - View to the user the ideal surfboard model according to his profile.
**How do I want / I'm doing**  - Getting user data (level of experience, Height, Weight and surfboard type), comparing them with my `reference list` and displaying to the user.
**How can I do this?**

Comment: So, as a start you obviously have two table - one which holds types of people, and one which holds types of boards. The people/person_type table might reference 3 other tables, which will hold details about skill levels, height ranges, and weight ranges respectively. The board types table could hold details about centres (in inches) and litres (in litres obviously). It might also reference 2 other tables; one holding details about board types, and one about board size ranges.

Comment: Please do not show so many example rows. Please give table definitions for the design you have now and what you are proposing. Make clear what table defintion/name goes with what example table and what meaning/purpose. Don't just make general statements that are not clearly connected to the part of the design they describe or lead to.