# What is the best method to compare data using the join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm doing a section on my website called "My Ideal Surfboard", the user enters their data (weight, height, etc.), a comparison is made in database (`join`) and is returned to the ideal types of surfboard user according to his profile.

I have a table with the reference of all sizes and types of surfboard according to height, weight and user experience.

[image: Reference table]

I'm doing the following:

Divided into two tables: 
  - Table `USER` obviously stores user data (experience, height and weight); 
  - Table `SURFBOARD` possesses the reference values (type, size, weight and litres) on each surfboardd according to experience, weight, height of the user.

-> I liken the table `USER` to the table `SURFBOARD` and return to the user the ideal model. How to do this?

At first I thought putting the same fields both in the table `USER` as in the table `SURFBOARD` make a `inner join` and have the data you want.

However, the both tables would duplicate values.

```
`dados_usuario`      `prancha` 
    height2           weight2
    height2           weight2
    height2           weight2
    height1           weight2
    height1           weight2
    height1           weight2
       I compare and I display...
```

I believe that this is not a good practice and not the best way to do this. I know there are other methods to do this.

The issue is,  **how best way to compare these data?** 

 **How to identify which line is compatible with the data that the user will enter?**

MY DATABASE:

```
CREATE TABLE USER(
     usuario INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     nome VARCHAR(150) not null,
     email VARCHAR(50) not null,
     estilo VARCHAR(14) not null,        
     exp VARCHAR(13) not null, 
     altura VARCHAR(12) not null,
     peso VARCHAR(9) not null,
     PRIMARY KEY(usuario)
);

CREATE TABLE SUFBOARD(
    prancha_pri INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,        
    tipo_prancha VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    tamanho_prancha VARCHAR(9) not null,
    meio_prancha VARCHAR(12) not null,
    litragem_prancha VARCHAR(8) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (prancha_pri)
);
```

INSERTING DATA IN TABLE 'USER':

```
INSERT INTO EXPERIENCIA VALUES (NULL, 'joao', 'a@a.com', 'Surf', 'INICIANTE', '<1,60m', '>90kg');
INSERT INTO EXPERIENCIA VALUES (NULL, 'john', 'b@b.com', 'StandUP Paddle', 'INTERMEDIARIO', '1,81 - 1,90m', '81 - 90kg');
INSERT INTO EXPERIENCIA VALUES (NULL, 'carl', 'c@c.com', 'Surf', 'AVANÇADO', '>1,90m', '71 - 80kg');
```

INSERTING DATA IN TABLE `SURFBOARD`:

```
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (1, 'FUN', '8', '21 polegadas', '43L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (2, 'FUN', '8.8', '21 polegadas', '43L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (3, 'LONGBOARD', '9.2', '21 polegadas', '55L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (4,  'PRANCHA', '5.5 a 5.8', '20 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (5,  'PRANCHA', '5.5 a 5.10', '20 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (6,  'PRANCHA', '5.9 a 6.0', '21 polegadas', '32L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (7,  'PRANCHA', '6.0 a 6.4', '21 polegadas', '34L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (8,  'PRANCHA', '5.10 a 6.4', '20 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (9,  'PRANCHA', '5.10 a 6.4', '20 polegadas', '32L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (10,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '32L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (11,  'PRANCHA', '6.4 a 6.8', '21 polegadas', '34L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (12,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '20 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (13,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (14,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '34L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (15,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '36L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (16,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '21 polegadas', '38L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (17,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 7.0', '21 polegadas', '34L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (18,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 7.0', '21 polegadas', '38L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (19,  'PRANCHA', '5.5 a 5.8', '18 polegadas', '23L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (20,  'PRANCHA', '5.8 a 5.10', '18 polegadas', '24L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (21,  'PRANCHA', '5.10', '18 polegadas', '27L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (22,  'PRANCHA', '6.0 a 6.2', '19 polegadas', '28L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (23,  'PRANCHA', '6.0 a 6.2', '19 polegadas', '29 a 31L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (24,  'PRANCHA', '5.10 a 6.0', '19 polegadas', '24L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (25,  'PRANCHA', '5.10', '19 polegadas', '26L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (26,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '27L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (27,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '29L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (28,  'PRANCHA', '6.2', '20 polegadas', '30 a 31L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (29,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '25L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (30,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '28L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (31,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '19 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (32,  'PRANCHA', '6.0 a 6.2', '20 polegadas', '30 a 31L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (33,  'PRANCHA', '5.11', '19 polegadas', '26L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (34,  'PRANCHA', '5.11', '19 polegadas', '28L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (35,  'PRANCHA', '6.0', '20 polegadas', '29L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (36,  'PRANCHA', '6.1', '20 polegadas', '30L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (37,  'PRANCHA', '6.1 a 6.6', '20 polegadas', '30 a 31L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (38,  'PRANCHA', '6.1', '19 polegadas', '27L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (39,  'PRANCHA', '6.1', '19 polegadas', '28L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (40,  'PRANCHA', '6.1 a 6.3', '20 polegadas', '29L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (41,  'PRANCHA', '6.1 a 6.4', '20 polegadas', '31L');
INSERT INTO PRANCHA VALUES (42,  'PRANCHA', '6.2 a 6.6', '20 polegadas', '31L');
```

In my form, visually they are all of height and weight exact values. However, the value of the fields are the values of my reference table:

HEIGHT:

```
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.71m</option>
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.72m</option>
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.73m</option>
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.74m</option>
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.75m</option>
<option value="1,71 - 1,80m">1.76m</option>
```

WEIGHT:

```
<option value="81 - 90kg">88Kg</option>
<option value="81 - 90kg">89Kg</option>
<option value="81 - 90kg">90Kg</option>
<option value=">90kg">91Kg</option>
<option value=">90kg">92Kg</option>
<option value=">90kg">93Kg</option>
<option value=">90kg">94Kg</option>
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this other question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37778529/3404097)? What is the difference between them?

Comment: Please explain "the both tables would duplicate values" The example data does not help.

Comment: In this question I just want to know how to compare the data by `INNER JOIN`. In the other question I want to know how to compare and displays. Yes, the content is very similar. It was my mistake, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks. It would be helpful if you edited the other question to remove its compariton parts.

Answer (score 1):

First *you* have to tell *us*, given a user and some boards, what makes the "ideal" board(s). Then that gets translated to SQL.

PS
You are going to have to remove units from your values if you want your queries to talk about those values using comparisons or arithmetic. (And then you can store numbers using numerical types.) You are going to have to store ranges as pairs of columns if you want to mention their endpoints easily. Otherwise you will have to write things like

```
U.HEIGHT >= get_min_from_range_as_number(B.HEIGHT)
U.WEIGHT <= get_weight_as_number_without_units(B.WEIGHT)
```

where the functions are complex.

---

Say you want rows where:

```
user USERID has ideal board(s) BOARDID
```

You have to tell us *what that means* in terms of simpler things. Eg perhaps it means that:

```
(read U.ID as USERID, B.ID as BOARDID)
there exist values for U.NAME, U.HEIGHT, ..., B.WEIGHT where
        user U.ID with name U.NAME ... has height U.HEIGHT...
    AND board B.ID suits height between B.MINHEIGHT and B.MAXHEIGHT ...
    AND U.HEIGHT >= B.MINHEIGHT AND U.HEIGHT <= B.MAXHEIGHT
    AND (B.MINHEIGHT + B.MAXHEIGHT)/2 <= U.WEIGHT * 100
    AND ...
    OR ...
```

---

Now we need a query that returns the rows that make that statement template into a true statement.

Already `User` holds rows where:

```
user ID with name NAME ... has height HEIGHT ...
```

And `Board` holds rows where:

```
board ID suits height between MINHEIGHT and MAXHEIGHT ...
```

But the nature of SQL `JOIN` is that *`table1 t1`*`JOIN`*`table2 t2`* holds the rows that satisfy the first table's statement template `AND`ed to the second's with parameters/columns prefixed by aliases and dots. So `User U JOIN Board B` holds rows where:

```
    user U.ID with name U.NAME ... has height U.HEIGHT ...
AND board B.ID suits height between B.MINHEIGHT and B.MAXHEIGHT ...
```

And the nature of `WHERE` is that *`table`*`WHERE`*`condition`* holds the rows that satify *table*'s statement template `AND`ed with *`condition`*. So

```
User U JOIN Board B
WHERE U.HEIGHT >= B.MINHEIGHT AND U.HEIGHT <= B.MAXHEIGHT
...
```

holds rows where:

```
    user U.ID with name U.NAME ... has height U.HEIGHT ...
AND board B.ID suits height between B.MINHEIGHT and B.MAXHEIGHT ...
AND U.HEIGHT >= B.MINHEIGHT AND U.HEIGHT <= B.MAXHEIGHT
...
```

Then `SELECT` drops any unwanted parameters/columns. So `user U.ID has ideal oard(s) B.ID` holds rows where:

```
SELECT U.ID, B.ID
FROM User U JOIN Board B
WHERE U.HEIGHT >= B.MINHEIGHT AND U.HEIGHT <= B.MAXHEIGHT
...
```

`SELECT` also renames columns. So to get our overall query of the rows where  `user USERID has ideal board(s) BOARDID` we need:

```
SELECT U.ID AS USERID, B.ID AS BOARDID
FROM User U JOIN Board B
WHERE U.HEIGHT >= B.MINHEIGHT AND U.HEIGHT <= B.MAXHEIGHT
...
```

Comment: I did differently from yours. I created two tables. The table `USER` and table `SURFBOARD`. In table `USER` I capture the infomation it (`exp`, `height`, `weight`). In table `SURFBOARD` I inserted all references values for each user profile (look my screenshot of reference table). So, I liken the `exp`, `height` and `weight` of table `USER` with same items of table `SURFBOARD`. And so I get the surfboard model according to the user profile.

Comment: What is your point? I know what your question says. What does this comment add? It is a bad idea to have a single column that is a range. But even if you do that, what is the statement template that says that a board is "ideal"?

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? I'm still getting to know the database, best practices, standardization and others.

Comment: See my extended PS. But if you please write out *the statement template that says "user USERID has ideal board(s) BOARDID" in terms of conditions and your current tables' statement templates* then you will see the difficulties.